# Why Salesforce Standard Lookup Auto-Completion not working when Visualforce Page has No Header showing

Tags: visualforce, lookup, inputfield, autocomplete

Is there a way to enable standard Salesforce `Lookup Auto-Completion` in `<apexinputField />` binded to an sObject Lookup Relationship field, when Visualforce Page is set to hide header via `showHeader="false"` ?

I've a Visualforce page, with header hidden, and with that I cannot open the Recent Items list for the inputField.

Is there a way I can override this, and have the recent items list always show up? Is this some UI bug in platform?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm whether you can use the autocomplete lookup in VF Page if showheader="true".

If No,

Please use the below URL which says you need to enable auto-completion.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=search_enhanced_lookup_enable_autocomplete.htm&type=0

Comment: Yes, I can use the Auto-Complete Lookups if `showHeader="true"`. And yes that particular setting is already On in my org.